# What's the best way to take the square root of an int?

Tags: go, type-conversion, math.sqrt

I ended up writing this recently to get around a problem that math.sqrt deals in floats:

```
for i := 2; i < int(math.Ceil(math.Sqrt(float64(n)))); {
```

I had to look away from the editor while doing it, but it worked. 
If a wandering helpful Gopher happens across this, what should I do instead?

(Context: was doing a quick prime factoring algorithm for a project euler problem.)

Comment: Why are you using ints?

Comment: Just off the cuff, this seems easier to read, and probably more accurate: `if float(i) < math.Sqrt(float64(n))` (certainly one doesn't have to wonder why `math.Ceil` was used, and if it's appropriate). Then you could also do `for i := 2.0; i < math.Sqrt(float64(n)); {`, unless you really need i to be an int for some reason.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps because later I was intending to do some modular arithmetic, and then I’d just be converting to ints for the arithmetic.